# Memory reference

Tags: java, equals-operator

Is `c` point to **a** or is `c` point to the **same memory** that `a` is pointing to?
Why does the following code print "We are equal"?

Thanks in advance

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String a = "10";
        String b = "10";
        String c = a;
        
        if(c.equals(b)) {
            System.out.println("We are equal ");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Not equal! ");
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Same issue with this code, why isn't ab equal to abc?
String a=”meow”;
String ab=a+”deal”;
String abc=”meowdeal”;
System.out.println(ab==abc);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java stores objects by reference... the reference just happens to be the value when we use primitives.

`int` is a primitive so

`a == c` => `true`

`a == b` => `true`

`b == c` => `true`

With Strings the situation is slightly different. `String`s are effectively char arrays: `char[]` but are not considered primitive types in Java.. so:

`"str1" == "str1"` => `false` since you're comparing two object references now.

For this reason the `Object` class has the `equals()` method which allows you to compare reference objects (non-primitives) via something other than the object reference ID. The `String` (a subclass of Object.class) class overrides the `equals` method.

In your example (above) you say:

> So why is `ab==abc` `false`. They are both pointing to same address.

This is incorrect. `ab` points to String that is "meowdeal" and `abc` points to a String that is also "meowdeal"... but crucially they are two distinct instances. Therefore:

`ab==abc` => `false` - here your checking for reference equality - are they the same object reference (no they are not)

`ab.equals(abc)` => `true` - here you're checking for string equality (is `ab`'s `"meowdeal"` the same as `abc`'s `"meowdeal"` - yes it is.

This is one of those curveball interview questions you might get from time to time so worth being aware of.